# Telnet commands automation through File or String in Java

Tags: java, telnet, apache-commons-net

I am automating the telnet commands using apache.commons.net in java. I am able to run the program as standalone, but basically the nature of telnet is interactive, how can I run telnet commands through file or string variable?

Comment: And your code is ...?

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to handle any interactive command-based interface programatically.

1. The simple way: Just have a list of commands, and send one after another with a small delay between them.
2. The complicated way: Have simple rule-based system, where you read from the remote system and matches the text against one or more rules. Depending on the matching rule, you then perform an action, like sending a command.

The first way is indeed simple, but it doesn't handle errors or problems very well. If there is a problem, which you will not notice, then continuing to send commands may actually make the problems worse.

The second way could in turn be implemented simple, like reading the text from the remote system, and if it doesn't match what you expect then simply bail. It could also be handled like a simple [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Suitably designed and implemented this might also be able to handle connection troubles gracefully.